# How do i use server-only functions in Next.js middleware?

Tags: javascript, next.js, middleware

I am using Next.js 13 with the App Router.

When trying to import a server-only fetch function into *middleware.js*, I get the following error message:

> **Error**: This module cannot be imported from a Client Component module.
> It should only be used from a Server Component. This error happened
> while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the
> terminal window.

That seems odd, because middleware is executed on the server and so is the imported function.

**middleware.js:**

```
import { getClientData } from "@lib/getClientData";

export default async function middleware(req) { ... }
```

**getClientData.js:**

```
import "server-only";

export const getClientData = async () => {
  const data = await ....
};
```

Why does Next not allow a server-only function to be imported into middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in [v13.4.20-canary.39](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v13.4.20-canary.39). You just need to install the latest version.
Related discussion: [middleware.ts treated as a client side component](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/54549).